# how to imelement node.js WebSocket support?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, serverside-javascript

i read that node.js can fully worked with WebSocket client.

my question is how to support WebSocket api in my node.js server side?
do i need to install something to support that, or just imepements build-in functions?

Comment: You get a module that supports the webSocket protocol and you load that module.  `socket.io` is the most popular, but it is not just a plain webSocket so you would have to use `socket.io` on the client side too.  NPM lists a number of node.js modules that offer plain webSocket support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/), it has both the library for client side and server side (node.js)

Answer (score 0):

Another good one is [primus](https://github.com/primus/primus), which wraps up a few different websocket libraries. It is active, and has good documentation for use.

**Note:** Primus does not, and will not, support socket.io v1.0 or greater So if you must have what socket.io is doing, be aware of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

socket.io is the most straight forward way to implement web sockets in your node app, handling both server-side (as an npm module) and client-side (a script that can be served from your server) features.

http://socket.io/